# How does a compiler know that a variable is global or local(C )

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction

I want to know that what happens inside the compiler...
like whether it store global variable at different location.

Comment: Get yourself a good book on basics of compiler. Might get some resources here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669/learning-to-write-a-compiler

Comment: Get yorself any book on C or C++. Got the the chapter about *scope*.

Comment: @honk a variable can be a global but not be in the global scope... scope and lifetime are different. (assuming that's what you meant)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: I was pretty sure that random book would mention `static` near that spot, but yes, my comment wasn't too helpful.

Answer (score 3):

The Wikipedia page on symbol tables can provide you a basic understanding.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_table

> In computer science, a symbol table is a data structure used by a
> language translator such as a compiler or interpreter, where each
> identifier in a program's source code is associated with information
> relating to its declaration or appearance in the source, **such as its
> type, scope level and sometimes its location.**
>
> [...]
>
> A common implementation technique is to use a hash table
> implementation. **A compiler may use one large symbol table for all
> symbols or use separated, hierarchical symbol tables for different
> scopes.**

Emphasis mine.

Answer (score 0):

It knows that the variable is global or local by how you declare it.

```
//declared at namespace scope - global
extern int x;     

int main()
{
   //declared inside a method - local
   int y;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally there are 4 scopes of any variables.
Using `extern` keyword you are making that variable extern explicitly.(by default global variables are `extern`)

Using `static`limiting the variable or function scope to it's current file

In accordance of that the memory are allocated in different segments

```
        global: visible in more than one source file
 -- data segement(also differs whether initialised or uninitialized)


        local : visible with in { } it also called function(){} scope
 -- on stack 


        block : {} inside any function another scope of block valiables with in {}

     -- on stack if with in function 


        file : making static variable is limited to it's file scope or 
    current translation unit. -- again data section
```